# AWS CLI User Data Script not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I'm trying to pass user data to my EC2 instance at the time of creation using AWS CLI run-instances command.

I placed the below command in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
echo "<html><h1>Welcome to the server</h1><html>" >> /var/www/html/index.html
```

All the AWS CLI command I ran(with .txt and without):

1. `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id  ami-062f7200baf2fa504 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name lab115key --security-groups my-sg --region us-east-1 --user-data file://./text1.txt`
2. `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id  ami-062f7200baf2fa504 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name lab115key --security-groups my-sg --region us-east-1 --user-data file://./text1`
3. `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id  ami-062f7200baf2fa504 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name lab115key --security-groups my-sg --region us-east-1 --user-data text1.txt`
4. `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id  ami-062f7200baf2fa504 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name lab115key --security-groups my-sg --region us-east-1 --user-data text1`

Then I tried to encode the script to Base64 still the User data is not accepted.

I created a Security group with port 80 and 22 with source 0.0.0.0/0
using Default VPC and Subnet.

> AMI: Amazon Linux 2 - t2.micro

```
Region: us-east-1
```

ISSUE:

1. HTTPD is not getting installed.
2. index.html is not getting created in the path.

Am I doing something wrong? Why is it not working?

Any other way to solve this issue?

---

### New Updates on this issue:

The User data that I passed to the `run-instances` command is getting installed but its taking too much of time.

Not all the time its getting installed. I ran the code five times, only 3 EC2 got User data installed.

From AWS Status Webpage: I found that `us-east-1` Is having lots of latency issues.

Comment: Is the instance in a public subnet so that it can download files from the Internet? Have you looked in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to confirm that the script is being executed and to check for errors?

Comment: I agree with @JohnRotenstein, check the log files.   I was unable to recreate the issue you were having.  Are you sure the default subnet it's being installed in has a route outside your VPC?  Can you run these commands manually?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, the instance is placed in a public subnet.

Comment: @kenlukas, Im able to SSH into that instance and run each command manually.

Answer (score 2):

Commands provided via User Data are executed as the `foot` user.

Therefore, **do not use `sudo` commands** within User Data scripts.

Any errors from executing a User Data script on Amazon Linux can be found in:

```
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log
```

If you are not sure whether the script is being executed, add a line like this after the header line:

```
echo Script started > /tmp/script.log
```

You can then check the contents of `/tmp/script.log` to determine whether the script was executed.

Comment: I was able to run my script through AWS CLI with **sudo** but its taking too much of time to run the command. At first I thought the code is not getting executed but it takes time. Now its working properly.